# Trying to download a file using Dropbox Java API in the GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an XML file on Dropbox that I want to access from my Google App Engine using the Dropbox Java API. After a bit of playing around I find the GAE doesn't support `FileOutputStream`.

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("myFile.txt");
try {
    DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/myFile.txt", null,
        outputStream);
    System.out.println("Metadata: " + downloadedFile.toString());
}
```

Any ideas how I can get the XML data into my GAE (client or server side) from Dropbox?
Thanks
Tim

Comment: why do you want to use `FileOutputStream`? `client` supports any `OutputStream` implementation

Comment: I'm using `FileOutputStream` as it is needed by the DropBox API `getFile` - code is from the DropBox java tutorial. It seems to accept `OutputStream` but how do I instantiate `OutputStream` as the constructor is protected? Sorry maybe I'm missing something here. Anyone got example code for reading a DropBox file in an GAE environment? Thank!

Comment: OutputStream is an interface, there're many implementation, depends of what you need. FileOutputStream for files, so it useless w/o files (mean on gae). ByteArrayOutputStream for example for in-memory data, that's probably what you need. And there're hundreds of other implementations. Including one for Google Cloud Storage. Also take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Thanks. `ByteArrayOutputStream` worked. So for anyone else trying to read a DropBox file in a Google App Engine environment (i.e. read into memory), here is what worked for me

```
String fileName = "myfile.xml"; OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
try { 
    dbxClient.getFile("/" + fileName, null, out); 
} catch (DbxException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} 

System.out.println("File Contente: " + out.toString());
```